# Meteor implementation of 'View x new Tweets'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm curious to know how you would implement something like Twitter's *"View x new Tweets"* functionality. Tweets being any data (blog posts, news items etc). eg: [see here.](http://cl.ly/image/1T0e2f3b0q0p)

Meteor by nature will pump any new data from a Subscription straight into your templates. While cool, sometimes you want to user to decide when new information should be shown.

My first thought is you would need two subscriptions:

**Subscription 1:** Returns all posts from now (timestamp) backwards.
**Subscription 2:** Returns a counter for all posts from now (timestamp) forwards.

So when you output the posts in your template you use subscription 1. which wont change because the timestamp locks it. However to show the number of new posts available *"View x number of new Posts"* you would use subscription 2. since it is always looking for new posts.

When the user clicks *"View x new Posts"* you simply update the first subscription to use the current timestamp. This would return all the latest in the new posts into your template.

Does this approach sound logical?

Comment: Ah perhaps I over thought it? Do you just do it all on the client side. So you subscribe to all your Posts and then only show the ones from a certain timestamp. And use .count() to know the difference between the ones being displayed and the ones that are new.

Comment: I think both options are valid. If there a lot of new posts then it's probably best to avoid sending the posts early, but if there aren't then handling it on the client would be easier.